# Is Inverse Search possible after the PDF file has been modified (e.g. annotated) (with Auctex and Okular)

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search

I have configured Okular and Auctex so that forward and inverse search work like a charm when I have the *.tex file open and after I compiled the PDF file. I do, however, often encounter a scenario where some other person comments, corrects or annotates this PDF file. Is there a way to configure okular (or any other PDF viewer) and emscas in a way that inverse seach is still working under these conditions? I.e. under conditions where I cannot recompile the PDF file?

Comment: Are you looking for a line of code that gets inserted into the preferences of the pdf reader to jump backwards to Emacs assuming that you kept the `.synctex.gz` file?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.

The .synctex.gz file links your TeX source file and the PDF output by postion. Supposing you complied `test.tex` and got the `test.pdf` file, you can find that even if you replace `test.pdf` by `aaaa.pdf`, forward and inverse searching will still work---position is right, however, the contents can be quite different.